# Cordova Android Development: Looking for OTG cable options for debugging with peripherals connected

Tags: java, android, cordova, printing, ionic-framework

I'm developing a Cordova Plugin for Android that interacts with a printer connected to my Android device's USB port. I also have Ionic in the mix running a working Anular application. I have the Plugin working, but getting to that point was painful. There were many iterations of deploying the app from my laptop (using ionic run Android) swapping the otg cable out and pluging in the printer and testing.

I'm looking for a better develop/debug story. I'm planning to add additional features to the Cordova plugin and would like to find a cable configuration that lets me keep the Android device connected to my laptop while the printer is also connected the Android device.

I've tried a few different after market cables, but everything seem to only support charging the device while connected to the peripheral devices. Nothing seems to allow me to stay connected to the laptop and have a peripheral connected simultaneously.

Is anyone aware of a USB Hub, Switch or Router that could help ease my pain, or have suggestions on how I can easily debug my Java based plugin while it is connected to the USB printer. At a minimum I'd like to be able to attach a debugger to my plugin and step through the Java code.

Using an Emulator is out of the question because the performance is simply unbearable.

Sorry in advance if this question is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a better solution for you, you can deploy to your device using adb over Wi-fi and keep your printer cable connected to test your app, here is how:

1. Connect your android device to your computer using a USB cable
2. From a command line run `adb tcpip 1234` // or any port of your chosing
3. disconnect your android USB cable
4. run `adb connect <your-phone-ip>:1234`
5. Connect your printer using the USB cable
6. run `ionic run android` to deploy your app.

I just tested this combo with a Mac and an Android Nexus 5 and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its a great solution to my problem. I found the same suggestion at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html under the Debugging Considerations section.